# VIATRA: Scope uninitialized in Query results

Tags: eclipse-emf

I am applying the guide in the "GETTING STARTED WITH VIATRA" tutorial (https://www.eclipse.org/viatra/documentation/tutorial.html) to writing a query for my model instances.

About my model: I created a metamodel in metamodel.ecore file, generated some instances, and save these instances in a model.xmi file.

At step 3.1.2. Evaluate Queries in the Query Results View, I cannot load models and queries using the Query Results View.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA9qb.png

I would like to ask how to initialize the Query Scope in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Better luck on the Viatra forum I think: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/147/

Comment: I created a new topic and asked about this matter in the Viatra forum. Thank you.

Comment: The answer for this question can be found here: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1836477/#msg_1836477